# Prove that $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{d_k}=2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a perfect number and $d_1 ,d_2,...d_k$ be the list of all positive divisors of $n$ prove that $$\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{d_k}=2.$$

I tried to do simplification but it reverses to the original problem.

Comment: Well, it *should* be equivalent to the fact that $n$ is a perfect number, so it sounds like you're close.  Please add your attempt at a proof to the question so we can show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  multiply by $n$ and assume the divisors are sorted in increasing order.  What is $\frac n{d_1}?$